# Salt times out when using external authentication (PAM)

Tags: python, authentication, salt-stack, pam

I'm trying to use **Salt (2015.8.10 Beryllium)** with "external_auth" via PAM.  My ultimate goal is to use salt-api to authenticate a request from a salt-minion which will allow that minion to call for it's own key to be accepted.  As a first step, it's suggested that you first get authentication working locally with "salt -a pam" on the salt master.  That's where I'm stuck.

The issue I'm having is that attempts to use pam are resulting in the Salt request timing out:

```
[root@saltmaster ~]# salt -a pam 'box603.example.com' test.ping --log-level all
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
...
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded pam.auth
username: user1
password: 
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/etc/salt/pki/master', 'saltmaster.example.com_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4506', 'clear')
[TRACE   ] Inserted key into loop_instance_map id 18446604434624361104 for key ('/etc/salt/pki/master', 'saltmaster.example.com_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4506', 'clear') and process 11045
[DEBUG   ] SaltReqTimeoutError, retrying. (1/3)
[DEBUG   ] SaltReqTimeoutError, retrying. (2/3)
[DEBUG   ] SaltReqTimeoutError, retrying. (3/3)
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
[TRACE   ] data = Salt request timed out. The master is not responding. If this error persists after verifying the master is up, worker_threads may need to be increased.
Salt request timed out. The master is not responding. If this error persists after verifying the master is up, worker_threads may need to be increased.
```

The host in question, box603.example.com is online and is pingable when not using pam authentication:

```
[root@saltmaster ~]# salt 'box603.example.com' test.ping
box603.example.com:
    True
```

My **saltmaster:/etc/salt/master** configuration file contains:

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    user1:
      - .*
```

And user1 is a valid user in /etc/passwd|shadow, it's usable via ssh, and I can su to it.

The docs indicate that when trying to authenticate with pam and salt, that it default's to pam's login service.  Here's my **/etc/pam.d/login**:

```
auth definitive         pam_user_policy.so.1
auth requisite          pam_authtok_get.so.1
auth required           pam_dhkeys.so.1
auth required           pam_unix_auth.so.1
auth required           pam_unix_cred.so.1
```

For what it's worth, the salt master is running **Solaris 11**.  I often see in posts for salt problems requests to post salt **--versions-report**, so here's that:

```
Salt Version:
           Salt: 2015.8.10

Dependency Versions:
         Jinja2: 2.8
       M2Crypto: 0.24.0
           Mako: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.11
          PyZMQ: 15.2.0
         Python: 2.7.11 (default, Mar 24 2016, 22:19:35)
           RAET: 0.6.5
        Tornado: 4.3
            ZMQ: 4.1.4
           cffi: 1.5.2
       cherrypy: 3.2.3
       dateutil: Not Installed
          gitdb: Not Installed
      gitpython: Not Installed
          ioflo: 1.5.1
        libgit2: Not Installed
        libnacl: 1.4.4
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.7
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: 2.14
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
         pygit2: Not Installed
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
          smmap: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed

System Versions:
           dist:   
        machine: i86pc
        release: 5.11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time Salt's "external_auth" pam implementation is tied directly to the Linux pam binaries and will only work on Linux.  So that means no Solaris, unfortunately.

Comment: It should be possible to use the Linux PAM external auth module as an example to make it work with Solaris. I just don't have a Solaris 11 box to test that on.